# 6 year old child being sexually active?

Tags: behavior

The first time I walked in my son's bedroom, he was playing with my friends niece (he was 4 and my friends niece was 2), and he had her pinned down on the bed and kneeling on her arms. She was screaming. The second time was with my friend (his dad's partner), and he asked her to bend over on the bed so he could kiss her neck and feel her boobs. We have caught him on a few occasions doing inappropriate things, but only to girls, and when no one is looking he tries something. He is 6 now, and we have a little girl who is 18 months, I was running a bath and she was on the bed naked, the little boy ran up the stairs, got in bed, and when I come back up stairs he had a guilty look on his face as he was trying to pull he's pants back up. What do you think I should do? I'm wondering whether or not to phone social services.

Comment: This isn't normal behavior for his age, and **his actions towards other children are abusive and dangerous**. Your question is far outside what parents-on-the-internet can provide advice about. This may be very serious and the child's parents or guardians should seek professional help as soon as possible.

Comment: Kids don't know this behavior at age 6.  He has probably seen video's and you need to find out how and who is presenting this material to him.  Then you should consider legal action.

Answer (score 9):

You should definitely seek professional help for this child, such as counseling.  This is not normal behavior for a child this age.

Getting counseling serves two purposes: protecting the other children he is around, and determining where this behavior is coming from.  As a foster parent, we typically see small children acting overtly sexual when that child has been abused themselves, or exposed to adult materials (pornographic videos or magazines, etc...)

A couple of similar questions:

[My son is five years old and sexually active](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/my-son-is-5-years-old-and-sexually-active?rq=1)

[4 year old son pursues sex with mom](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21455/4-yo-son-pursues-sex-with-mom?lq=1)

Chart showing normal and abnormal behaviors in small children:

[American Academy of Pediatrics - Chart of sexual behaviors in children](http://www2.aap.org/pubserv/psvpreview/pages/behaviorchart.html)